# How to display phonenumber using decimal format

Tags: java, decimalformat

Hello I would like to use **DecimalFormat** to display:

`8392472` as

`839 24 72`

I have tried

```
DecimalFormat dc = new DecimalFormat("000 00 00");
return dc.format(number);
```

I have also tried `"### ## ##"`

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do that with a `DecimalFormat` because your spaces are not group or decimal separators.

The simple way would be to simply use a string:

```
int number = 8392472;
String s = String.valueOf(number);
String formatted = s.substring(0, 3) + " " 
                 + s.substring(3, 5) + " "
                 + s.substring(5, 7);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think easiest way to achieve this is as below.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int number = 8392472;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(String.valueOf(number))
                                .insert(3," ")
                                .insert(6," ");
    System.out.println(sb.toString());    
}
```

Comment: This is slightly less efficient as it will involve copying the underlying array twice - that will probably not make a noticeable difference in most cases.

Comment: Any phone number with leading 0's will mess up. Used to be, in the US and Canada, all area codes began with the digit 2-9 and had 0 or 1 as the 2nd digit. The 2nd digit part isn't true any more. I don't know if the first digit can be 0 now.

Answer (score -1):

Use the library of Google! It works well for us.

https://code.google.com/p/libphonenumber/