# Java Format Number with Blanks

Tags: java

I have a number like this:

```
1234567890123
```

and want to format it for example like this

```
12 34567 89012 3
```

or maybe like this

```
1-234 567-890 1 23
```

How can I achive that? I tried this

```
DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("00 00000 00000 0");
System.out.println(decimalFormat.format(1234567890123L));
```

But this doesn't work.

I need a way to specify a pattern that can contain any separator character.

Comment: Is this even possible with DecimalFormat?

Comment: Why don't you use string.replace* ?

Comment: @ernest_k that's not possible with DecimalFormat. That's why I'm asking how to do that

Comment: @GauravJeswani This is just on possible format. There may be others. So I need a formatting solution

Comment: Well, this can be done with custom "number format" code, but for the sake of readability, I'd just use something like `"1234567890123".replaceAll("(^\\d{2})", "$1 ").replaceAll("(\\d{5})", "$1 ")`

Comment: @ernest_k To be more precise the format string can be specified from "outside" So I cannot use such a programmatic solution

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set space separator to float DecimalFormat?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28432122/how-to-set-space-separator-to-float-decimalformat)

Comment: @RazvanFulea I've updated my question please check it out

Comment: @SimonMartinelli from the link that I sent you, you can simply replace the parameter here `formatSymbols.setGroupingSeparator(' ')` with whatever separator you'd like

Comment: @RazvanFulea but what if I want to have - for the first two separators and blank for the others?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli sounds like a rather specialized use case, so you might want to write your own custom number formatter then. I don't think DecimalFormat allows that much flexibility

Comment: [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16015653/how-to-display-phonenumber-using-decimal-format)

Comment: @AvenDesta I already checked out these but they only solve a specific problem I need a generic solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @McPringle I finally implemented this solution:

```
public class MaskFormatter {

    private char[] separators;

    public String formatNumber(Number number, String pattern) {
        if (number == null) {
            return "";
        } else {
            separators = pattern.replace("0", "").toCharArray();

            String string = number.toString();
            String regex = createRegex(pattern);
            String replacement = createReplacement(pattern);

            return string.replaceAll(regex, replacement);
        }
    }

    private String createRegex(String pattern) {
        String[] parts = pattern.split("[" + createPatternFromSeparators() + "]");

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (String part : parts) {
            sb.append("(\\d{").append(part.length()).append("})");
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }

    private String createReplacement(String pattern) {
        String[] parts = pattern.split("[" + createPatternFromSeparators() + "]");

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {
            if (i > 0) {
                char separator = separators[i - 1];
                sb.append(separator);
            }
            sb.append("$").append(i + 1);
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }

    private String createPatternFromSeparators() {
        Set<String> set = new HashSet<>();
        for (char separator : separators) {
            set.add(String.valueOf(separator));
        }
        return String.join("", set);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```java
import java.text.ParseException;
import javax.swing.text.MaskFormatter;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

public class FormatTest {

    @Test
    void testNumberFormat() throws ParseException {

        final String format = "#-### ###-### # ##";
        final String number = "1234567890123";

        MaskFormatter maskFormatter = new MaskFormatter(format);
        maskFormatter.setValueContainsLiteralCharacters(false);

        System.out.println(maskFormatter.valueToString(number));
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem with that solution is that it's in the module java.desktop that may not be present on a server Java version created with JLINK

Comment: You could access the `MaskFormatter` dynamically and fallback to no format when not available. Maybe with some log output for an explanation.

Comment: @SimonMartinelli You should have stated that in your question when you originally asked it. Kinda unfair to change the requirements after receiving answers which basically invalidate the answer.

Answer (score 1):

That is not possible with `DecimalFormatter` and `NumberFormatter`. But you can use a trick with `String` and regular expression:

```java
Long.toString(number)
    .replaceAll("(\\d{2})(\\d{5})(\\d{5})(\\d)", "$1 $2 $3 $4");
```

If your format is dynamic, you could do something like this:

```java
@Test
void simon() {
    final var input = 1234567890123L;
    assertEquals("12 34567 89012 3", formatMyNumber(input, "{2} {5} {5} {1}"));
    assertEquals("12-34567-89012-3", formatMyNumber(input, "{2}-{5}-{5}-{1}"));
    assertEquals("12_34567_89012_3", formatMyNumber(input, "{2}_{5}_{5}_{1}"));
    assertEquals("1 23456 7", formatMyNumber(1234567, "{1} {5} {1}"));
    assertEquals("1 2345 6", formatMyNumber(123456, "{1} {4} {1}"));
    assertEquals("123.45.6", formatMyNumber(123456, "{3}.{2}.{1}"));
}

private String formatMyNumber(final long number, final String format) {
    return Long.toString(number).replaceAll(createRegEx(format), createReplacement(format));
}

private String createRegEx(final String format) {
    final var separator = getSeparator(format);
    return format.replaceAll("\\{", "(\\\\d{")
            .replaceAll("}" + Pattern.quote(separator), "}\\)")
            .replaceAll("}$", "}\\)"); // could be integrated in above regex
}

private String getSeparator(final String format) {
    final var begin = format.indexOf("}");
    final var end = format.indexOf("{", begin);
    return format.substring(begin + 1, end);
}

private String createReplacement(final String format) {
    final var separator = getSeparator(format);
    var replacement = format.replaceAll("^\\{\\d", "\\$X")
            .replaceAll("}" + Pattern.quote(separator) + "\\{\\d", separator + "\\$X")
            .replaceAll("}$", "");
    var counter = 1;
    while (replacement.contains("X")) {
        replacement = replacement.replaceFirst("X", Integer.toString(counter++));
    }
    return replacement;
}
```

It's not my best piece of work but works with dynamic format strings.

Comment: Ok, you updated your question - no idea for that, now.

Comment: I can do this as a challenge tomorrow. :-)

Comment: This helps a lot already! I will need two formatting string. First to create the regex and the second to create the format

Comment: Or something like `"{2} {5} {5} {1}"` and create the two strings dynamically from that one string.

Comment: `1234567L` becomes `1234567` not `1 23456 7`.

Comment: @mokyade That was not the question... ;-)

Comment: This works if all separators are the same but not for the second example in the question: 1-234 567-890 1 23

Comment: Well, should not be a huge deal (hint: separator-array). But I leave it to you now, some Pizza-invitation is waiting for me today. Can help you tomorrow, if needed.

Comment: No that's fine. Enjoy the pizza :-)

Answer (score 0):

Here's something to get you started.  Feel free to modify the code to meet your needs.

```
public class ArbitraryFormat {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArbitraryFormat arbitraryFormat = new ArbitraryFormat("00 00000 00000 0");
        System.out.println(arbitraryFormat.format(1234567890123L));
        System.out.println(arbitraryFormat.format(123));
    }
    
    private int zeroCount;
    
    private String formatter;
    
    public ArbitraryFormat(String formatter) {
        this.formatter = formatter;
        this.zeroCount = countZeros(formatter);
    }
    
    public String format(long value) {
        String tempFormatter = "%" + zeroCount + "s";
        String temp = String.format(tempFormatter, value);
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        
        int tempIndex = 0;
        for (int index = 0; index < formatter.length(); index++) {
            if (formatter.charAt(index) == '0') {
                builder.append(temp.charAt(tempIndex++));
            } else {
                builder.append(formatter.charAt(index));
            }
        }
        
        return builder.toString();
    }
    
    private int countZeros(String formatter) {
        int count = 0;
        int index = 0;
        
        while (index < formatter.length()) {
            int pos = formatter.indexOf('0', index);
            if (pos >= 0) {
                count++;
                index = pos + 1;
            } else {
                index = formatter.length();
            }
        }
        
        return count;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define your own formatter like this.

```
public class MyFormat extends NumberFormat {

    final String format;

    public MyFormat(String format) {
        this.format = format;
    }

    @Override
    public StringBuffer format(double number, StringBuffer toAppendTo, FieldPosition pos) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    @Override
    public StringBuffer format(long number, StringBuffer toAppendTo, FieldPosition pos) {
        toAppendTo.append(number);
        for (int i = toAppendTo.length() - 1, j = format.length() - 1; i >= 0 && j >= 0; --i, --j) {
            char fch = format.charAt(j);
            if (fch != '*') {
                toAppendTo.insert(i + 1, fch);
                --j;
            }
        }
        return toAppendTo;
    }

    @Override
    public java.lang.Number parse(String source, ParsePosition parsePosition) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }
}
```

And

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
    long number = 1234567890123L;
    MyFormat mf1 = new MyFormat("* ***** ***** *");
    MyFormat mf2 = new MyFormat("*-*** ***-*** * **");
    System.out.println(mf1.format(number));
    System.out.println(mf2.format(number));
}
```

output:

```
12 34567 89012 3
1-234 567-890 1 23
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `String.replaceAll()`. Like the following example.

```java
long value = 1234567890123L;
String str = String.valueOf(value);
        
//12 34567 89012 3
String str1 = str.replaceAll("^(.{2})(.{5})(.{5})(.{1})$", "$1 $2 $3 $4");
System.out.println(str1); //Prints: 12 34567 89012 3

//1-234 567-890 1 23
String str2 = str.replaceAll("^(.{1})(.{3})(.{3})(.{3})(.{1})(.{2})$", "$1-$2 $3-$4 $5 $6");
System.out.println(str2); //Prints: 1-234 567-890 1 23
```